# How to findout codec of a video?

Tags: video, codec, avi

I bought a CSS tutorial. It has many videos that can not played by anything expect their own player.  The format of videos are AVI but when you play them it play as sound only and no sound plays.

I want to play it with other media players too. I tried to change its format to many other formats but nothing new happen. So I need to understand its real format or codec to play it with others or convert it.

[This is one of its shortest parts](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ihaxxhg9s06zwtl/8244%282%29.avi) (4.8 MB, language is not English). Any information will help.

Comment: Have you tried VLC? That plays just about anything, on any desktop platform. Failing that, this site is perhaps not an ideal place to get support - contact the seller.

Comment: seller Isn't giving me any information for It think I share them but that player is too basic.and I tried vlc, kmp, media player classic,and of course windows media player.

Comment: There is a great tool for that called [mediainfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo).However, both mediainfo and ffplay barf at your file...

Comment: If it doesn't play in VLC, ask them to re-encode it, or to offer you a refund.

Comment: @halfer you didn't understand my question correctly.It can be played by it's own player.but can't by others.

Comment: Ah right, gotcha. If you were made aware of that when you purchased it, you might be stuck. It's still not a programming question though, as far as I can tell, and so off-topic here - maybe ask at SuperUser? (If you do so, please add a note so it does not attract duplicate answers).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the sample. I downloaded and inspected the data with a hex editor and it is absolutely not a straight AVI file. It looks like it is encrypted. Remove that encryption and it might actually be a plain AVI file underneath.

Can you tell me what player is required to play this? Did you have to register the player somehow? I'm trying to understand whether the encryption key would be built into a player license or into the player itself.

Comment: yeah.there is a videoplayer included in software specially for playing this files.It need license.I find out someone decrypted 2 of videos and placed them on youtube. so It's possible.one of them:www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gSABlmHFGA